# Does Heidi sql allow you to add more than one foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

I have successfully added my first FK in heidisql using the foreign key tab and adding all the appropriate sections.

I have tried to do the same to my second related column both by using the FK tab and by running a query but I keep getting an error.

`SQL Error (1005): Can't create table sprout.#sql-430_3 (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"`)

sprout is my db name so I have no idea why it is saying cant create table sprout (because I'm not referencing it in my query).

**sql query for my first FK(generated via heidisql):**

```
ALTER TABLE `purchase_history`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `bus_id` FOREIGN KEY (`bus_id`) REFERENCES `business` (`bus_id`);
```

**sql query for my second FK(generated via heidisql)**

```
ALTER TABLE `purchase_history`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `bus_name_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`bus_name`) REFERENCES `business` (`bus_name`);
```

**sql query I wrote to try and add second FK**

```
Alter table purchase_history
Add constraint bus_name_fk
Foreign key (bus_name)
references business(bus_name);
```

Can someone help explain to me how my constraint is incorrectly formed? To my understanding I was able to add another constraint to the the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Huh?  Why are you adding two foreign constraints to the same table . . . but using *different* columns?  That doesn't really make sense.  In general, the foreign key should be referencing the primary key of the other table, which I presume is `bus_id`.

Then, if you want the business name, you can use a `join` to get the name.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes a lot more sense.